# Get Related Products for SellableItem in custom plugin

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

I need programmatically import catalog from 3rd party service to Sitecore Commerce 9. I can create Catalog, Category and SellableItem. I can add related product for SellableItem, but I couldn't get a list of already added related products for my SellableItem.

How can I get list of related products for SellableItem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve related products for 6042069 sellable item:

```
var id = "relatedproduct-6042069";
var findResult = this._findEntitiesInListPipeline.Run(new FindEntitiesInListArgument(typeof(Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.SellableItem), id, 0, 100), context.ContextOptions).Result;
var result = findResult.List.Items;
```

Where _findEntitiesInListPipeline is IFindEntitiesInListPipeline